# Adding textbox on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The following code will add new textbox on click event, but after When I click submit button the newly added textbox  is not saving.
please solve this issue.

html

```
<table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td id="container_width">
            <input type="text" name="width" placeholder="" />
        </td>

        <td id="container_height">
            <input type="text" name="height"placeholder="" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" name="increment" id="increment" value="+">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save settings"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


//javascript

$('#increment').click(function(){
    var width = document.getElementById("container_width");
    var input;
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name ="width[]";
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    width.appendChild(br);
    width.appendChild(input);

    var height = document.getElementById("container_height");
    var input;
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name ="height[]";
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    height.appendChild(br);
    height.appendChild(input);
});
```

Comment: When you add elements using javascript, then visually those elements will appear as part of form but in actual they will not be part of form submission.
So on click of submit button your newly created textbox values will not be saved.

Try calling an ajax method to save the values.

Comment: How to create ajax method for "added elements using javascript to save values".

Answer (score 3):

Add [] to the initial text inputs name. That should solve the problem:

```
<input type="text" name="width[]" placeholder="" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="height[]" placeholder="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName"></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp;
        <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addCF").click(function(){
    $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName"></label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldName" name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="Input Name" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
});
$("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
});
```

Try [This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1z4f1ga9/), You can dynamically add and delete table rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Elements Dynamically using jQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click the button and each will perform some dynamic function!</p>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Add Element" class="bt" />
        <input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Remove Element" class="bt" />
        <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Remove All" class="bt" /><br />
    </div>
</body>
            
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var iCnt = 0;
        // CREATE A "DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING jQuery ".css()" CLASS.
        var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',
            borderTopColor: '#999', borderBottomColor: '#999',
            borderLeftColor: '#999', borderRightColor: '#999'
        });

        $('#btAdd').click(function() {
            if (iCnt <= 19) {

                iCnt = iCnt + 1;

                // ADD TEXTBOX.
                $(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
                    'value="Item ' + iCnt + '" />','<input type=date class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' + 'value="' + iCnt + '" />');

                // SHOW SUBMIT BUTTON IF ATLEAST "1" ELEMENT HAS BEEN CREATED.
                if (iCnt == 1) {
                    var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
                    $(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt"' + 
                        'onclick="GetTextValue()"' + 
                            'id=btSubmit value=Submit />');
                }

                // ADD BOTH THE DIV ELEMENTS TO THE "main" CONTAINER.
                $('#main').after(container, divSubmit);
            }
            // AFTER REACHING THE SPECIFIED LIMIT, DISABLE THE "ADD" BUTTON.
            // (20 IS THE LIMIT WE HAVE SET)
            else {      
                $(container).append('<label>Reached the limit</label>'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable'); 
                $('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });

        // REMOVE ONE ELEMENT PER CLICK.
        $('#btRemove').click(function() {
            if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; }
        
            if (iCnt == 0) { 
                $(container)
                    .empty() 
                    .remove(); 

                $('#btSubmit').remove(); 
                $('#btAdd')
                    .removeAttr('disabled') 
                    .attr('class', 'bt');
            }
        });

        // REMOVE ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE CONTAINER.
        $('#btRemoveAll').click(function() {
            $(container)
                .empty()
                .remove(); 

            $('#btSubmit').remove(); 
            iCnt = 0; 
            
            $('#btAdd')
                .removeAttr('disabled') 
                .attr('class', 'bt');
        });
    });

    // PICK THE VALUES FROM EACH TEXTBOX WHEN "SUBMIT" BUTTON IS CLICKED.
    var divValue, values = '';

    function GetTextValue() {
        $(divValue) 
            .empty() 
            .remove(); 
        
        values = '';

        $('.input').each(function() {
            divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
                padding:'5px', width:'200px'
            });
            values += this.value + '<br />'
        });

        $(divValue).append('<p><b>Your selected values</b></p>' + values);
        $('body').append(divValue);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
$('#increment').click(function(){
 var html = "<input type="text" name = "newText" id = "textId">
$(this).append(html);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first wrap your inputs in a form. Then as suggested by in other responses, change the original width and height to width[] and height[]. Also since you're already using jQuery you could use it to add the elements (not necessary though).

```
<form id="exampleForm">
<table class="form-table">



    <tr valign="top">
        <td id="container_width">
            <input type="text" name="width[]" placeholder="" />
        </td>

        <td id="container_height">
            <input type="text" name="height[]" placeholder="" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" name="increment" id="increment" value="+">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save settings"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

JSCode:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#increment').click(function(){
      var width = $("#container_width");
      var input;
      var input = $("<input>").attr("type","text").attr("name","width[]");
      var br = $("<br>");
      width.append(br);
      width.append(input);

      var height = $("#container_height");
      var input = $("<input>").attr("type","text").attr("name","height[]");
      var br = $("<br>");
      height.append(br);
      height.append(input);
  });
});
```

Example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1rh480kq/1/

Comment: When I refresh the page the saved textboxes are disappears..how to solve this issue

Comment: @Nivin That's way beyond the scope of this question as this requires the use of server side technology and knowing what your code does. The idea is to dynamically populate the <inputs> using a server side language  (I'll assume you're using PHP) e.g. `<td id="container_width"> <?php foreach ($results as $result) echo "<input type=...>" ?> </td>`. You can probably find more sources on how to do this online.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to call your server side method

```
    var txtValList = [];
    txtValList.push($('txtVal1').val());
    txtValList.push($('txtVal2').val());
    txtValList.push($('txtVal3').val());
    $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "ServerSideMethod",
                data: JSON.stringify(txtValList),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //On success
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert('some error occurred');
                }
            });
```

Also you can refer [this link](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/create-html-table-using-jquery-ajax.html) to see how to use ajax and WebMethod

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#increment').click(function(){
   var width = $("#container_width");
   var input;
   var input = $("<input>").attr("type","text").attr("name","width[]");
   var br = $("<br>");
   width.append(br);
   width.append(input);

   var height = $("#container_height");
   var input = $("<input>").attr("type","text").attr("name","height[]");
   var br = $("<br>");
   height.append(br);
   height.append(input);
  });
});
```